# Getting the unique year value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I just wanted to extract unique year value from this date type column. But I always get this error "You might need to add explicit type casts".

[image]

If there are 2020-06-23, 2020-07-01, 2019-01-02, 2019-02-05 dates, my desired output is to return the unique year values. So the output should be 2020 and 2019 only.Please help. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
$year= DB::table('loans')
            ->select('date_release', DB::raw('YEAR(date_release) as year'))
            ->groupBy('year')
            ->get();
```

Comment: what if there are many different years such as 2019, 2018 ?

Comment: Not sure if you can group by an "alias" (which I think you are using as a string), try `->groupBy(YEAR(date_release))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are only 2 ways to get what you want
first you need add another column with name year and store data only year and your query will be like this

```
return DB::table('loans')
    ->select('year')->distinct('year');
```

second one is before return you should some algorithm to extract year and return only distinct year it will be like this

```
$year =  DB::table('loans')
    ->select([DB::raw('YEAR(date_release) as year')])
    ->groupBy('year')
    ->value('year');
$distinct_year = array();
foreach($year as $item){
    $years = date('Y', strtotime($item->year))
    if(!in_array($years, $distinct_year)){
         array_push($distinct_year, $years);
    }
}
return $distinct_year;
```

Answer (score 3):

The query could be (returns all when there are different dates from different years);

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM loans.date_release) AS year FROM loans group by year;
```

The query builder will be

```
return DB::table('loans')
    ->select([DB::raw('EXTRACT(YEAR FROM loans.date_release) as year')])
    ->groupBy('year')
    ->pluck('year');
```

it prints following for multiple years

```
[2018, 2019, 2020]
```

Comment: sorry, but what I want also is even if there other years like 2019 and 2018, it will return like "2020, 2019 and 2018"

Comment: If there are 2020-06-23, 2020-07-01, 2019-01-02, 2019-02-05 dates, my desired output is to return the unique year values. So the output should be 2020 and 2019 only.

Comment: @Eli updated the answer, let me know if there is a problem

Comment: it returns an error. SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function year(date) does not exist LINE 1: select YEAR(date_release) as year from "loans" group by "yea... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select YEAR(date_release) as year from "loans" group by "year")

Comment: @Eli so you have postgresql, you didn't mention that in question or tags. updated again.